# Running .NET Core on Opensuse 13.2

Tags: c#, .net

I have tested .NET Core on Windows & Ubuntu succesfully ( Console & ASP.NET 5 app).
I am now trying to run a simple console app, followed by a web app on OpenSUSE 13.2 x64. I have followed the tutorial found [here](http://dotnet.github.io/docs/getting-started/installing/installing-core-linux.html) , but with no success.

I have installed the DNX using the dnvm tool, and tried a simple hello world program:

**program.json**

```
{
    "version": "1.0.0-*",
    "dependencies": {
    },
    "frameworks" : {
        "dnx451" : { },
        "dnxcore50" : {
            "dependencies": {
                "System.Console": "4.0.0-beta-*"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**program.cs**

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello, Linux");
        Console.WriteLine("Love from CoreCLR.");
    }
}
```

Running
**dnvm list**

```
Active Version              Runtime Architecture OperatingSystem Alias
------ -------              ------- ------------ --------------- -----
       1.0.0-rc1-final      coreclr x64          linux
       1.0.0-rc1-final      mono                 linux/osx       default
  *    1.0.0-rc1-update1    coreclr x64          linux
       1.0.0-rc2-16237      coreclr x64          linux
```

The problem is that neighter dnu restore / dnu build / dnx run does anything, it throws no error and does nothing.

Comment: I had this same exact issue and gave up. Hopefully someone can provide an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the guys developing .NET core, [this](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/37) is due to an incorrect version of libicu. So, I have downloaded the source files from [here](http://site.icu-project.org/download/52) and used [this](http://source.icu-project.org/repos/icu/icu/tags/release-52-1/readme.html#HowToBuildUNIX) tutorial to build and install libicu52.1.

```
unzip icu4c-52_1-src.zip
cd icu
mkdir build
cd build
 ../source/runConfigureICU Linux/gcc CXXFLGS="-D__STRICT_ANSI__ "
make -j4
sudo make install
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib64
```